# jQuery: Group <a> links based on text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, filesystems

jQuery noob here - needing some help.

Basically, because Go's html/template output sucks, I'm forced to use more JS (which I suck at!)

I have an ordered, but not grouped list of links, that need grouping into "parent folder" links, by the text value.  Like a file/folder tree.

The list is dynamic, but based as follows:

```
<div id="Files">
<a>file.rb</a>
<a>Somefile.rb</a>
<a>folder</a>
<a>folder/level2</a>
<a>folder/level2/file.js</a>
<a>folder/level2/level3/anotherfile.js</a>
</div>
```

So files would need to be grouped into their parent folder, and folders grouped recursively by the text in the 'a' element.  The parent 'a' would be the 'folder' and the child the 'files' within that folder.

Unfortunately, Folder and File 'a's can't be given separate classes on generation due to the underlying Go script.  The output is just a fully expanded directory of folders / files in ordered, but not grouped links.

RE: comment below:  The example desired output is something like the following:

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/

I understand this could mean splitting the files/folders into ul/li lists, but I'm fine with that.  It's the detection of file vs folder & folder level from the link text I am struggling with.

Any help is MUCH appreciated!  Thanks! :)

Comment: Give an example of what you're looking for. I have an idea what you want but I need an example of the final product from the example above. Thanks. ***

an html example of the final product***

Comment: Replied to this in the question - thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/6hWsK/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aList = $('#Files > a');
    var fileList = [];
    $.each($('#Files > a'), function(i, obj){
        fileList.push($(obj).html());
    });

    var tree = GetNodeTree(fileList);
    console.log(tree);
    var html = DrawMenu(tree, "http://www.google.nl");
    console.log(html);
    $('#Files').html(html);
});

function GetNodeTree(fileList){
    if(fileList.length === 0){
        return [];
    }
    var childTree = [];
    $.each(fileList, function(i, path){
        var nodeNames = path.split("/");
        if(childTree[nodeNames[0]]===undefined){
            childTree[nodeNames[0]] = [];
            childTree[nodeNames[0]]['files'] = [];
        }
        if(nodeNames.length>1){
            var childPath = nodeNames.slice(1).join("/");
            childTree[nodeNames[0]]['files'].push(childPath);
        }
    });
    for(var key in childTree) {
        childTree[key]['name'] = key;
        childTree[key]['files'] = GetNodeTree(childTree[key]['files']);
    }
    return childTree;
}

function DrawMenu(tree, basepath){
    var elements = "";
    for(var key in tree) {
        var node = tree[key];
        var path = basepath + "/" + node['name'];
        var childMenu = DrawMenu(node['files'], path);
        elements += $('<div><li><a href="'+ path + '">' + node['name'] + childMenu + '</a></li></div>').html();
    }
    if(elements.length>0){
        elements = '<ul>'+elements+'</ul>';
    }
    return $('<div>'+elements+'</div>').html();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  The only discrepancy is it seems to generate sub-ul's for links that have no  children:  http://i.rbin.co/xlV4

Comment: Perfect!  But it seems to have removed the links from the li's.  Each li should just be a link to itself.

Comment: Here is the last update I've got for you: http://jsfiddle.net/6hWsK/
It creates A tags with the path to the corresponding file. Replace http://www.google.nl with your base-webaddress.

Comment: Thankyou so much.  Massive help!  :)